# Flutter InAppPurchase products not showing on release build

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've added the `in_app_purchase` flutter package and was working fine on debug (followed the setup instructions etc.) but when I build the release apk it cannot find any of the products, all are returned under `notFoundIDs` without stating any error.

I've tried `flutter clean`.
Also Tried using the exact same `buildTypes` config on both, same result.

Any idea why the release build would not return any queried items? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, found the problem, 
apparently `queryProductDetails([...])` needs to be called **after** `isAvailable()` returns true.

I had both calls running asynchronously and for some reason it was working in debug mode but not release.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a reserved SKU for the test: android.test.purchased

```
const List<String> _kProductIds = <String>[
  'android.test.purchased'
];
ProductDetailsResponse productDetailResponse =
  await _connection.queryProductDetails(_kProductIds.toSet());
```